# CToolBar with checkbox only - not showing properly

Tags: mfc

I have an MFC `CToolBar` (dockable to a `CFrameWnd`) containing a checkbox and a button.

This works fine now, but I need to remove the button, and then the `CToolBar` does not show properly any more. As it seems because it gets "zero" height. The checkbox style is "turned into" a `TBBS_SEPARATOR` using a call to `CToolBar::SetButtonInfo` before it is "created".

How can I make the toolbar visible also without that dummy button?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by overriding the CToolBar::CalcDynamicLayout method and provided the size of the toolbar there. Then the button was not needed any more. This assumes the toolbar is created with CBRS_SIZE_DYNAMIC.